# Custom function description in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-2013, comments

lets say i have a function

```
double addNumbers(double a, double b) {
    return a+b
};
```

i want my VS to pop up a description of this function as i am trying to call it:

```
addNumbers(
 <pop up info> double addNumbers(**double a**, double b)
 << This function takes two real numbers -> a and b and returns their sum >>
```

where "pop up info" is default message but the thing between << and >> is not shown and i really like it to be shown. How do i achive it?

Comment: What generates the <pop up info> text and the line following it?

Answer (score 0):

I would start at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177226.aspx) page.

Example:

```
///Function to add two floats.
float add(float a, float b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Triple-slash comments are your friend:

```
/// This function takes two real numbers a and b and returns their sum
double addNumbers(double a, double b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

But note that Visual Studio only uses that description in the statement completion pop-up:

[image]

and not in the parameter help pop-up:

[image]